# What is the smallest value of $n$ for which $f_n(x)$ is a constant polynomial

Tags: polynomials

Let $f_1(x)=(x+53)(x+106)(x+159)\cdots(x+2014)$. Define $f_2(x)=f_1(x+1)-f_1(x)$ ; $f_3(x)=f_2(x+1)-f_2(x)$ ; $\ldots$ ; $f_n(x)=f_{n-1}(x+1)-f_{n-1}(x)$. What is the smallest value of $n$ for which $f_n(x)$ is a constant polynomial?

The only thing I could figure out was that 106= 2(53); 159 = 3(53) and 2014=38(53). That's about it, any suggestions?

Comment: Prove that if $g(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)$ then $g$ is of degree one less than $f$ (unless $f$ was a constant already). For extra credit observe that the same holds if you set $g(x)=f(x+n)-f(x)$ for any constant $n$.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: If you don't see it try it with easier polynomials first. For example, what happend´s when $f(x)=x^2$, what happens when $f(x)=x^3$, when $f(x)=x^3+x^2$ etc.

Comment: Ok, so when $f(x)=x^2$ then $g(x)=(x+1)^2-x^2 = 2x+1$. But how do I translate this to the question?

Comment: Observe the degrees! Calculating $g(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)$ is not unlike taking the derivative $f'(x)$. It is not the same thing, but not too different either. I'm sure you could easily figure out how many times you would need to differentiate $f_1(x)$ to get a constant.

Comment: Now I see it, 39 times! Thank you sir, I'm actually starting my PhD classes this Fall 2018, so I'm trying to get myself ready. I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72024/discussion-between-joshua-bonet-and-jyrki-lahtonen).